# USB ports on external monitor are not recognized

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-monitor

I have an external monitor (ASUS PB238Q) connected to my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop via HDMI.  The monitor works totally fine except for the four USB ports on it, which are not recognized by Ubuntu.

Opening a terminal and typing `lsusb` shows that it doesn't detect when I connect a device.  I also tried `dmesg | tail` which has no change while connecting or disconnecting a device to the monitor's port.

The USB ports on my laptop, as well as the port on my external keyboard work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you connect the USB hub cable to your computer? It's a [USB-B plug](http://www.bestpcmonitors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pb238q.jpg) next to those two USB ports.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin, thanks!  That solved it.  Could you convert your comment to an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to connect the USB hub cable to your computer,

It's a [USB-B plug](http://www.bestpcmonitors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pb238q.jpg) right next to those two USB-A ports.